# how to determine if a specific value exists in a string of comma-separated values?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that stores information about customers. I have a variable that stores countries in which the customer has lived. This variable can hold many values at once e.g. "england, scotland, wales". It may be worth mentioning that these values are gained through input.

I then later on in the code want to check what values the customer has entered. In this example the customer has entered the three values above. I want to determine if the customer has entered scotland.

How do I search the original variable that holds the three values for the one value "scotland"?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some code illustrating where you're stuck?

Comment: I mean... you could use some like string.ToLower().Contains("scotland"). You you could use string.Split(',') and look at the array. If it's user input there is no way to guarantee that they will divide countries with commas

Comment: `bool scotlandExists = countries.Split(',').Contains("scotland");`

Comment: `bool scotlandExists = countries).Contains("scotland");` This may be less accurate, though, since it's not splitting on any defined separator character, so a country that has a name that's a subset of another country may return a false positive.

Comment: `This variable can hold many values at once e.g. "england, scotland, wales".` I'd suggest changing that variable to not be a `string` but be a `List<string>`. Using the wrong datatype, as you are here, is going to make these kinds of problems harder and harder. Use the right datatype, and the problem just disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string.Split you can split into the individual countries:

```
var countries = stringVariable.Split(',').Select(_ => _.Trim()).ToArray();
```

then search for the country

```
if (countries.Contains("scotland", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
}
```

Comment: only problem is this is unfiltered user input. No way to ensure they will type in lowercase letters, or split countries with commas.

Comment: Indeed, other possible separators can be added to the Split call, e.g. `.Split(',', ';', ' ')`. Ignoring case is realized by the StringComparer in my solution.

Comment: The answer is correct, but i don't like the use of `_` in the lambda. Comes down to personal preference ultimately, but i wouldn't use a character here that's reserved for the discard of outs.

Comment: @BoredomOverload bad habit from pre-C#7 times... I have always problems finding good names for lambda parameters. Many people use one-character names like `x` which I don't like, too. Descriptive names are often already used in the enclosing scope. To me it seems there is a language feature missing, something like an expression-local name scope.